# Change Illuminate\Support\Collection of Illuminate\database default return type to array version 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm using `Illuminate\Database` package of laravel as a standalone database connector for my core PHP code. I'm trying to upgrade the code with newer version i.e. 5.8, interestingly the new version of this package now returns the query results as `\Illuminate\Support\Collection` object. Due to this I need to change my existing queries by appending `->toArray()` method. Is there any way so that I can convert the default return type of the collection to Array, or any middleware or hook to manipulate the query results as an Array?

Below is my existing query which is working fine in old version

```
$MYDBOBJ->db->table("user")->select("*")->where("status", 'Active')->get();
```

If I need to fix this then I need to modify my query like below:

```
$MYDBOBJ->db->table("user")->select("*")->where("status", 'Active')->get()->toArray();
```

The above will work in new version but I need to change it in lots of files.

If I do not use toArray() method then I'd get the results wrapped in

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [something] => somestring
                )
        )
 )
```

And I require it as Below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [something] => somestring
        )
)
```

So is there any way to overcome this option and manipulate the query results as an Array?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. I have been looking in to this myself a few months ago and concluded that the query builder is [hard-wired](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L2115) to return a Collection.

You could create a macro for the Query Builder, but you would still have to edit all your queries to use the new macro function.

Comment: In this case I'd end up with appending toArray() method to every query rather than creating a macro

Answer (score 0):

I came up with one solution by extending `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` class with a new class and overriding `get()` method. 
Below is the extended class code:

```
<?php


namespace Illuminate\Database\Query;

use Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

class QueryBuilder extends \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
{
    //@Override
    public function get($columns = ['*'])
    {
        return $this->onceWithColumns(Arr::wrap($columns), function () {
            return $this->processor->processSelect($this, $this->runSelect());
        });
    }

    public function pluckFromArrayColumn($queryResult, $column, $key)
    {
        $results = [];

        if (is_null($key)) {
            foreach ($queryResult as $row) {
                $results[] = $row[$column];
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($queryResult as $row) {
                $results[$row[$key]] = $row[$column];
            }
        }
        return $results;
    }
}
```

I simply removed `collect` function call and returned the results.
I also did the same thing with `pluckFromArrayColumn` by overriding it.
I also changed the namespace in Illuminate/database/Connection.php as follows:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder as QueryBuilder;
//to
use Illuminate\Database\Query\QueryBuilder as QueryBuilder;
```

And finally in the connection setup portion, as belows:

```
$dispatcher = new Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
            $dispatcher->listen(Illuminate\Database\Events\StatementPrepared::class, function ($event) {
                $event->statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            });
$capsule->setEventDispatcher($dispatcher);
```

I'm still exploring for the best possible way but as of now this tweak works for me :)